# Convert manual colored maps to vector

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, color, vectorization

Is there a way to colorimetrically and automatically vectorize georeferenced rasters that came from manually colored, scanned maps? Currently we Print the  topography maps 20k scale --> hand-coloring work (hazard mapping) --> georeferencing (perfectly, if I may say so) ---(current stage)--> digitization of manually colored map.

If a solution exists i know some eye-to-screen adjustment would still be in order though I believe this path would be easier in the long run.

Comment: this is almost like land cover classification - at least some raster re-classification can be done once you've scanned the map - how many colours are you dealing with? Once reclassified to 'just' those colours, converting to vector based should be easy...

Comment: Yes, I have seen the r.reclass command. I'm just worried about satellite rasters vs crayon marks..I mean, how would the computer analysis fare.

Comment: it's all pixels, right? Do you have a little snippet you can post of what the scanned image looks like?

Comment: I have seen this done in ERDAS many (many, many) years ago with supervised classification on 50k and 100k printed topographic maps. Select your 'training areas' wisely! Other software would be able to do it (with varying degrees of success) but in the end the biggest factor is selecting your 'training areas' wisely - be prepared to do several iterations to get it right. Depending on the level of detail it should be quicker than heads-up digitizing.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble uploading a 1.4 MB jpg. Right now, I've merged the scanned, georeferenced maps in QGIS using Raster > Miscellaneous > merge. It's now in GRASS, where the RGB bands were apparently loaded separately, and all is B&W...

Comment: ... like this you can make it a "multi-channel" classification (use the RGB viewer to see it in colors but for classification you want the channels separately).

Comment: It pretty much *is* image classification. Working with colored maps should be much simpler than trying to classify a sat image - there's a much smaller color palette in theory and areas of similar color are much likelier to be part of the same thing. Somewhat related question, where I talk about the RGB issue and ways to address it in order to arrive at a single classified value from the three that make up a color: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126236/ It's from an ArcGIS perspective though, and I don't know enough about GRASS or QGIS to name analog tools if there are any.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't mark a correct answer to this question. The project already concluded. But I believe I will still need learn this in the very near future!